# Elasticsearch mapping_parser_exception error

Tags: magento2.2.4, elasticsearch

I'm running Elasticsearch 7.6 on my Cloudways staging server, and 7.8 with Homebrew on my local server. Using Magento 2.4 (now 2.4.1).

When I try to reindex, I see

```
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","
reason":"analyzer [sku] not found for field [sku]"}],
"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"analyzer [sku] not found for field [sku]"},"status":400}
```

When I click on test connection under catalog > search, it says successful, and my Mirasvit search plugin says that I'm connected

Any idea of what this could be?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue when using Mirasvit Search Ultimate on version 2.0.9, update to version 2.0.10 which was released on the 20th October 2020 and this resolved the issue for me.

https://mirasvit.com/docs/module-search-ultimate/current/changelog

Comment: Thanks. I upgraded, and the error is gone. They still haven't fixed the pagination issue, which means that my customers are getting a lot of 524 errors while search tries to put sometimes 2k+ products onto a page...

Comment: @webmaster I've not got a pagination issue with the site I use the extension on so maybe that is something else.

Comment: Did you upgrade to Magento 2.4 yet? When I messaged Mirasvit, they said that they they know of the issue, and they're fixing it